# Several instances of several tables in one form (Symfony2, Doctrine and Twig)

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I am learning Symfony2, answers for all my previous questions I found via search. But my last issue is too hard and nothing close was found. 
Here is the issue.

I have:

- `Resgroups` Entity (the groups of resources), it consists of 2 fields: `id` and `ResgroupName`;
- `Roles` Entity, it consists of 2 fields: `id` and `RoleName`;
- `FTE` Entity, it consists of 4 fields: `id`, link to `Resgroups`, link to `Roles` and `FTEAmount`.

Each `Resgroup` should include all `Roles`, so I would like to render one form which includes:

- `ResgroupName`
- 1-st `RoleName` + `FTE Amount` for 1-st `Role`;
- 2-st `RoleName` + `FTE Amount` for 2-st `Role`;
- ...
- Last `RoleName` + `FTE Amount` for last `Role`;
- `Insert / Update` button.

At present time I can render a form with one `ResgroupName`, `RoleName` and `FTE Amount`.

Is it possible to make something like this via Symfony2+Twig? 
I need only the way where to look.

I have tried to use `Collection`

```
$builder->add('fte', 'collection', array('type' => new FTEType()));
```

but I received Null for `fte` object
`dump` of `form` in `twig` :

```
FormView {#829 ▼
  +vars: array:27 [▶]
  +parent: null
  +children: array:8 [▼
    "Resgroupname" => FormView {#995 ▶}
    "fte" => FormView {#1326 ▼
      +vars: array:29 [▶]
      +parent: FormView {#829}
      +children: []
      -rendered: false
    }
```

FTEType Class:

```
class FTEType extends AbstractType {

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder->add('resgroup', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Resgroup',
        'choice_label' => 'resgroup'));

    $builder->add('rolelist', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\RoleList',
        'choice_label' => 'roleListName'));

    $builder->add('amount', 'number');
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like your want a collection: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

Comment: I tried to use Collection but it dosn't work. I add some code.